# Facebook XFBML is not rendering in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8, xfbml, ie-developer-tools

I put up this test page to illustrate this issue: (dead Link)

Every browser I've tested on has worked but in Internet Explorer 8. The odd part is that Internet Explorer 8 doesn't even report an error, WOW, and that is something. So right now I'm stuck with to nothing to work on or debug. What have I overlooked?

Comment: I notice in the source that the href attribute is in single quotes only for the fb div. Could that be it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So somehow the `xmlns` attribute that I had previously set to the HTML tag was gone, probably me undoing things like crazy.

Here is how it should be if anyone encounters this issue:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it's not so easy find that trick about the xmlns.

Comment: Thank you. I pulled my hair on this... Since i work with HTML5 i put it conditionally: <!--[if (lte IE 8)]><html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="sv" class="no-js ieLte8"> <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head></head>

<body>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">

</script>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="500" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

</body>

</html>

Even this is not working in the IE. It is opening a pop up url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_reload.html and that's that. On Debugging I see it is not picking up the xmlns. Same code works fine in FF and Chrome and I am able to see on my facebook wall also but not if I do through IE.