# Facebook like button not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, browser, facebook

I have added the XFBML facebook like button.

It shows fine in Chrome and FF, but not IE.

I have also added this to the HTML tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

The language of the LIKE button is in swedish... (Not that I think it matters)

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [Facebook XFBML is not rendering in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933075/facebook-xfbml-is-not-rendering-in-internet-explorer-8) and http://digitizor.com/2010/07/06/fix-facebook-connect-xfbml-not-showing-ie/

Just use `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

Comment: When I use the send button (true), it doesn't show, only without the send button